# Arduino UNO and TB67H303HG Ic driver: Wiring question

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, wires

I would like to control the [TB67H303HG](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/docget.jsp?did=15071&prodName=TB67H303HG) (a full bridge driver IC for DC motor
adopting MOS in output transistor) with my Arduino UNO.
This is its [datasheet](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/docget.jsp?did=15071&prodName=TB67H303HG).

I was thinking to connect:

- **PIN 3 INPUT** to Arduino Digital Output 13 and set it to LOW to use the direct PWM mode
- **PIN 5 Vref** to 24VDC
- **PIN 6 Vcc** to 24VDC
- **PIN 7 STBY** to Arduino pin 8
- **PIN 8 IN1** to Arduino Pin 12
- **PIN 9 IN2** to Arduino Pin 11
- **PIN 16 OUT1A** and **12 OUT1B** in parallel to the Motor
- **PIN 14 OUT2A** and **10 OUT2B** in parallel to the Motor
- **PIN 13** and **17** to GND
- **PIN 20 Vcc** to 24VDC
- **PIN 22 PWM** to Arduino PWM 10

I do not know if I'm wrong, but I think I should use IN1 and IN2 to select the motor spin rotation and the Pin 12 PWM to change the velocity by setting the Arduino pin 10 with the PWM output from 0 to 255. Is it correct?

Can you tell me if the wiring is correct?
Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 3):

The Vref potential should not be 24V. As mentionned in the datasheet:

Vref = 0.3V to 1.95V depending on what you want.

Comment: sorry for the mistake, you are right! Thank you for the correction! Do you think the other considerations are OK?

Comment: Maybe the pin 23 is to connect with a resistor of 51kOhms ? For the clock